# Android: German SIM card users: getSimOperatorName() test

Tags: android

this question is only relevant if you have a German SIM card provider. Can you run the following code and post the answer here? (Obeying upper and lower case please).

```
package com.testing.sim;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class testSim extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);

        TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tv.setText(tMgr.getSimOperatorName());
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot! The more answers the better, if you see the same string as posted just add a comment, me too or something like this.

Comment: Why don't you just use [getSimCountryIso()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso())?

Comment: because I need the operator and not the country

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the us, but if you really need to identify the carrier, it would be better to use `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()` and then look up the mccmnc here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code and hardcode that in your app,

```
if (telMan.getSimOperator().equals("26201")) {
//respond appropriately
}
```

Not sure if it matters or not, but if you are trying to ID the carrier, that would be most concrete and sure way to do it.

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't show on that wikipage all the resellers. I guess they run under the normal brand. Do they? E.g. Aldi Talk is a reseller of E-Plus, should that now show Aldi Talk or E-Plus? Where E-Plus is on the list and Aldi Talk not, I need to know that this is Aldi Talk. E-Plus is not enough to know.

Comment: I have no idea... In the US, I don't believe the resellers have all that many android users, so I don't know if it would be worth going all out for. Regardless, my only guess would be to call them and ask. In the US, sim cards have an ICCID and IMSI, for AT&T the first 6 digits are the same: 310410. So, if they have IMSIs on their SIMSs, then likely they'd all start with the mccmnc. I work for att, btw. That's why I know this. Upgrading network technologies on a network (CDMA/UMTS to LTE) might change the mccmnc, not sure though

Comment: I really doubt that the customer service will know what you mean by mccmnc, though. If you tell them the IMSI thing, though, they might be able to figure it out, maybe.